# Cloudinary.url is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm wanting to convert an image url so it can include the transformation properties (I want to change the width and height). Here is an example of what I store in my database (the url Cloudinary gives us when we upload an image)

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/blah/image/upload/v15/orsdrkjfddaqjlwsk0t.jpg
```

I'm using `node.js` and the `cloudinary` library gives us the following method: `cloudinary.url()`.

It does not seem to work when I pass the cloudinary image URL to it:

```
cloudinary.url('https://res.cloudinary.com/blah/image/upload/v15/orsdrkjfddaqjlwsk0t.jpg',
{ width: 100, height: 100 });
```

It will just return the original url, it won't add any transformation values to it?!

Note: I what I did to get it to work was strip `orsdrkjfddaqjlwsk0t.jpg` from the url & pass it to the cloudinary.url method. However if the image stored in my database is not one from cloudinary, stripping the `nameofimage.jpg` from the url won't work! Cloudinary will create a cloudinary URL for it WHICH does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a crop mode for the width and height to take into effect. For example,

```
cloudinary.url('https://res.cloudinary.com/blah/image/upload/v15/orsdrkjfddaqjlwsk0t.jpg',
{ width: 100, height: 100, crop: "scale"});
```